# SQLite query for finding file path

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a column in my SQLite database that contains a file path.  Given a portion of the file path, I need to return all the next folders.  I would also like to return whether the next portion is the last path in the string (or does not end in a '/').  So if I have the folders:

```
/my/folder/one
/my/folder/two
/my/folder/path/three
/another/path
/one/two/three
```

And I have the path:

```
/my/folder/
```

The result would return something along the lines of:

```
+----------+------+
| isLast   | item |
+----------+------+
|    1     | one  |
|    1     | two  |
|    0     | path |
+----------+------+
```

I've been struggling with this for a while so if anyone can provide any guidance it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the folder paths in SQL already?

Comment: Yes, the folder paths are stored in a separate column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT item NOT GLOB '*/*' AS isLast,
       item
FROM (SELECT substr(MyPath, length('/my/folder/') + 1) AS item
      FROM MyTable
      WHERE MyPath GLOB '/my/folder/' || '*')
```

will give you a result like this:

```
isLast  item
------  ----
1       one
1       two
0       path/three
```

Removing the subpath requires the [`instr()` function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr), which was only recently introduced in SQLite 3.7.15:

```
SELECT isLast,
       CASE WHEN isLast
         THEN item
         ELSE substr(item, 1, instr(item, '/') - 1)
       END AS item
FROM (SELECT item NOT GLOB '*/*' AS isLast,
             item
      FROM (SELECT substr(MyPath, length('/my/folder/') + 1) AS item
            FROM MyTable
            WHERE MyPath GLOB '/my/folder/' || '*'))
```

Comment: 3.7.15 was released 6 days ago! Turns out your answer is behind the cutting edge. ;) Perhaps you'd like to update it to show what can be done with `instr()` at your disposal?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using this for an Android app.  I doubt SQLite will be updated any time soon :).  But thanks for updating anyways!